# Sett scope on javascript function call

Tags: javascript

I want to call a javascript function within a protected scope and i can do it this way

```
var a = "Global a";
( function() {
    var a = "Local a";
    var alertA = function() {
      alert(a);
    }
    alertA(); 
})();
```

This alerts "Local a" butt what i realy would like to do is to get the same result with an already declared function.

```
var a = "Global a";
var alertA = function() {
    alert(a);
}

( function() {
    var a = "Local a";
    alertA(); 
})();
```

So my question is how can a call alertA with a different scope so the result would be "Local a"

The reason i would like to do this i want to call globally defined functions on different iframes and have global variabels like document and window point to the appropriate documents and windows for every specific iframe.

Comment: You can't, your only chance is to pass the value as argument.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Then make the functions accept `window` and `document` as parameters. This decouples your code, makes your functions easier to reuse and their purpose clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me put it as an answer:

I suggest you make the function accept `window` and `document` as argument:

```
function someFunc(window, document, otherParameter) {

}
```

In each frame, you can then take its `window` and `document` as pass it to the function. For convenience, you can create a wrapper function in each frame, which does this for you:

```
var localSomeFun = function() {
    return someFun.apply(null, [window, document].concat(arguments));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
var a = "Global a";
var alertA = function () {
    alert(a);
}

(function () {
    var a = "Local a";
    alertA.apply(window, []);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to refactor your code a bit, I enclose my solution:

```
var a = "Global a",
    alertA = function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    };

alertA();

(function() {
    var context = {};

    context.a = "Local a";

    alertA.call(context);
})();
```

You will have to store all variables in a specialized `context` object. Inside a function you will need to use `this.%variable_name%` instead of plain `%variable_name%`.